# Convert coldfusion json to struct

Tags: json, coldfusion, struct, cfml

I have a JSON variable output from a jQuery application as so:

```
[{"id":1},
{"id":197,"children":[{"id":198},{"id":199},{"id":200}]},
{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":143},{"id":6},{"id":5},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12}]},
{"id":15,"children":[{"id":17},{"id":190},{"id":191},{"id":131},{"id":16},{"id":142},{"id":124}]},
{"id":149,"children":[{"id":150},{"id":160},{"id":161},{"id":184}]},
{"id":20,"children":[{"id":132},{"id":127},{"id":152},{"id":107},{"id":108},{"id":109},{"id":110},{"id":125},{"id":128},{"id":130},{"id":129},{"id":112}]},
{"id":162,"children":[{"id":163},{"id":164},{"id":165},{"id":166},{"id":186},{"id":187}]},
{"id":167,"children":[{"id":173},{"id":168},{"id":170},{"id":169},{"id":192},{"id":194}]},
{"id":174,"children":[{"id":176},{"id":175},{"id":188}]},
{"id":153,"children":[{"id":178},{"id":179},{"id":195},{"id":154},{"id":157}]},
{"id":180,"children":[{"id":181},{"id":182},{"id":183},{"id":189}]},
{"id":122},
{"id":21},
{"id":13},
{"id":92},
{"id":22},
{"id":113},
{"id":114}]
```

I need to convert this variable to a struct and then loop the struct by the first `id` parameter to find the children for each `id` (if there is one).  I have tried to convert it as a structure like so but I am getting an error:

```
<cfset jsonarray = deserializeJson(output)>
<cfloop collection="#jsonarray#" index="id">
<cfdump var="#jsonarray[id]#">
</cfloop>
```

It does not recognize the variable as a structure:

```
Invalid collection [{id={1}}, {children={[{id={198}}, {id={199}}, {id={200}}]},id={197}}, {children={[{id={3}}, {id={143}}, {id={4}}, {id={6}}, {id={5}}, {id={7}}, {id={8}}, {id={9}}, {id={10}}, {id={11}}, {id={12}}]},id={2}}, {children={[{id={17}}, {id={190}}, {id={191}}, {id={131}}, {id={16}}, {id={142}}, {id={124}}]},id={15}}, {children={[{id={150}}, {id={160}}, {id={161}}, {id={184}}]},id={149}}, {children={[{id={132}}, {id={127}}, {id={152}}, {id={107}}, {id={108}}, {id={109}}, {id={110}}, {id={125}}, {id={128}}, {id={130}}, {id={129}}, {id={112}}]},id={20}}, {children={[{id={163}}, {id={164}}, {id={165}}, {id={166}}, {id={186}}, {id={187}}]},id={162}}, {children={[{id={173}}, {id={168}}, {id={170}}, {id={169}}, {id={192}}, {id={194}}]},id={167}}, {children={[{id={176}}, {id={175}}, {id={188}}]},id={174}}, {children={[{id={178}}, {id={179}}, {id={195}}, {id={154}}, {id={157}}]},id={153}}, {children={[{id={181}}, {id={182}}, {id={183}}, {id={189}}]},id={180}}, {id={122}}, {id={21}}, {id={13}}, {id={92}}, {id={22}}, {id={113.... Must be a valid structure or COM object.
```

Comment: @Leigh has got you on the right track as far as a general solution goes. Also note that you're deserialising the JSON into a variable `jsonarray` then referencing it as `session.jsonarray`. Those are two different variables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In [JSON](http://json.org/), the `[]` denotes an array and `{}` a structure (or object). So your input is actually an array of structures. You need to use an `array` loop, not a collection loop:

```
<cfset arrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(output)>
<cfloop array="#arrayOfStructs#" index="parent">
      <cfset parentID = parent.id />
      ... 
</cfloop>
```

`children` is also an array of structures. Inside the outer loop, check for the existence of that key. If found, loop through the child array and do something with each of the id's:

```
  <cfif structKeyExists(parent, "children")>
      <cfloop array="#parent.children#" index="child">
          ...
      </cfloop>
  </cfif>
```

Answer (score 2):

A tidy cfscript version.  :)

```
<cfscript>
    structObj = deserializeJson(jsonString);

    for(i = 1; i LTE ArrayLen(structObj); i++){

        WriteOutput("parent id : " & structObj[i].id & "<br>"); 
        if(StructKeyExists(structObj[i], "children")){
            for(j = 1; j LTE ArrayLen(structObj[i].children); j++){
                WriteOutput("    -children id : " & structObj[i].children[j].id & "<br>");
            }
        }
    }
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an Angular 1.4 ColdFusion 9 JSON Normalizer [here](https://gist.github.com/richfergus/6c739b8100bf0cd1c6c7)

```
 var myURL = 'myCfc.cfc?method=getItemsFromDb';
 var app = angular.module('angularOutput',[]);
 app.controller("sectionController", function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get(myURL).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          var log = []; 
          var output = '';
          angular.forEach(data.DATA, function(value, key) {
                    this.push(output +='{"value": ');
                    this.push(output += '"'+value[0]+'"');
                    this.push(output +=',"text":');
                    this.push(output += '"'+value[1]+'"');
                    this.push(output +='}');
                    this.push(output +=',');
                }, log);
              output = output.replace(/,\s*$/, "");/*had to remove the final comma */
              output = '['+output+']'; /*had to add the [] to corectally form the output*/

          $scope.sections = angular.fromJson(output);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data);
        });
    });
```