# How to check if value of an object is null or not in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have an object called `jsonJobsOpen` and when I dump it the output shows the value for this Object as shown below.

```
[{
    "APPLICATIONCOUNT":0,
    "JOBNAME":"Candidate Migration Job&nbsp;",
    "JOBID":"15433AAE-8631-FA8B-AEA7-49E116EF60E1&nbsp;",
    "JOBCLOSEDATE":" ",
    "JOBSTATUSLABELVALUE":"Incomplete",
    "ENCRYPTEDURLAPPCOUNT":"event=cms.listApplicantsPersistVars&amp;JobID=15433AAE-8631-FA8B-AEA7-49E116EF60E1&amp;JobAppStatusID=DCA85CD5-A134-7A4B-30E8-49E116F0D702",
    "JOBOPENDATE":" ",
    "APPLIEDAPPCOUNT":0,
    "JOBSTATUSLABELCOLOUR":"D8605F",
    "REFERENCE":"Candidate Migration Job&nbsp;",
    "ENCRYPTEDURL":"event=jm.gotoJCW&amp;JobID=15433AAE-8631-FA8B-AEA7-49E116EF60E1",
    "ENCRYPTEDURLCANDIDATEASSESSMENT":"event=jm.gotoJCW&amp;JobID=15433AAE-8631-FA8B-AEA7-49E116EF60E1",
    "ENCRYPTEDURLAPPLICANTLIST":"event=cms.listApplicantsPersistVars&amp;JobID=15433AAE-8631-FA8B-AEA7-49E116EF60E1"
}]
```

If there is no value associated with Object then the dump looks like this:

```
[{
    "JOBID":"",
    "JOBOPENDATE":"",
    "JOBCLOSEDATE":"",
    "JOBNAME":"",
    "REFERENCE":"",
    "ENCRYPTEDURL":"",
    "APPLICATIONCOUNT":"",
    "ENCRYPTEDURLAPPLICANTLIST":"",
    "ENCRYPTEDURLCANDIDATEASSESSMENT":"",
    "JOBSTATUSLABELVALUE":"",
    "JOBSTATUSLABELCOLOUR":"",
    "APPLIEDAPPCOUNT":"",
    "ENCRYPTEDURLAPPCOUNT":""
}]
```

My question here is what condition can I use to check if the value is there or not with this object in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 2):

[From Leigh's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775222/1636917)

> In JSON, the `[]` denotes an array and `{}` a structure (or object). So your input is actually an array of structures. You need to use an array loop ...

```
<cfset arrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(jsonJobsOpen)>
<cfloop array="#arrayOfStructs#" index="thisValue">
    <!--- Now you can use this condition to check for empty values --->
    <cfif StructKeyExists(thisValue, "JOBID") and Len(thisValue.JOBID) GT 0>
    ... 
</cfloop>
```

I'm doing a couple things there. First deserializing the JSON string into something ColdFusion can handle (an array of structures). Then checking that the `JOBID` field exists. If it does exist, then also check that it's length is greater than 0 (not empty).

You should be able to do something like this for each element (assuming that the name of your variable containing this JSON is `jsonJobsOpen`.

Here is a quick [ColdFusion Gist](http://trycf.com/gist/7212b4778f3fe0ac4d345115c21871cf/acf2016?theme=monokai) that shows an example using your data.

Comment: @abhikumar I am glad it helped you. Don't forget to mark this as the answer so others will see it.